Relationship between row spaces of two matrices when the null space of one is a subspace of the other
For two real matrices A and B, if the null space of A is a subspace of that of B, does that imply that the row space of B is a subspace of that of A? I think the answer is yes because if not, then there exists one row in B which cannot be written as a linear combination of the rows in A. It implies that B is a linear combination of both the rows in A and the vectors in the null space of A, where the coefficients on the latter are not all 0. If that is the case, then the inner product between this row vector in B and this combination of the vectors in the null space of A is not 0, contradicting the fact that the null space of A is a subspace of that of B.
Is the reasoning correct? Many thanks.

I think your reasoning is correct. Stated more simply, your statement follows from the facts that null space and row space of a matrix are orthogonal complements, and the operation of orthogonal complement reverses the direction of inclusion of subspaces under the usual inner product on $\mathbb R^n$.

Thanks a lot @Pranay! That’s a great point! The statement becomes so obvious using this argument.
